# VBA Selecting a range for multiple sheets

Tags: vba, loops, charts, subroutine

I am trying to use a sub routine to run through 10 team names in a sheet called Parameter. Each of the team names has its own sheet. I am trying to get the user to select the range and then have my sub run through and create charts for the 10 teams based on the range selected.

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range
Dim r As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim TeamName As String

Set rng = Application.InputBox( _
Prompt:="Select a range.", _
Title:="Obtain Range Object", Type:=8)

r = "'" & TeamName & "'!" & rng.CurrentRegion.Address(ReferenceStyle:=xlR1C1)

For i = 1 To 10

TeamName = Sheets("Parameter").Range("E" & i).Value 'identify the location

Call charts(TeamName) ' Call subroutine

Next i

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Sub charts(TeamName As String)
Dim strTitle As Integer
Dim chtObj As ChartObject
Dim i As Integer


For Each chtObj In ActiveSheet.ChartObjects
chtObj.Delete
Next

For i = 1 To 42 Step 4

j = j + 1


Endrow = Range("A1").End(xlUp).Row - 1

Set Range1 = r.Offset(Endrow, i + 1)

Sheets(TeamName).Select

strTitle = j

MyFunction = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLineMarkers
ActiveChart.HasLegend = False
ActiveChart.HasTitle = True
ActiveChart.ChartTitle.Text = "PC " & j
ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range1

Dim MyWidth As Single, MyHeight As Single
Dim NumWide As Long
Dim iChtIx As Long, iChtCt As Long

MyWidth = 300
MyHeight = 200
NumWide = 5

     iChtCt = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects.Count
     For iChtIx = 1 To iChtCt
         With ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(iChtIx)
             .Width = MyWidth
             .Height = MyHeight
             .Left = ((iChtIx - 1) Mod NumWide) * MyWidth
             .Top = Int((iChtIx - 1) / NumWide) * MyHeight
         End With
     Next

ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryCategoryAxisNone)
ActiveChart.SetElement (msoElementPrimaryValueGridLinesNone)

Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I don't see why not. You can select Sheets by using ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("yoursheetname").Range("yourrange") --- and you can get a range's current range using rangeObj.address

Comment: would this allow the user to only have to define the range once?

Comment: i have updated my attempt

Comment: What issues are you having?

Comment: i get a object required error 424 on line "Set Range1 = r.Offset(Endrow, i + 1)"

Comment: r is a string as you have it programmed, you need to do something like Set Range1 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("yoursheet").Range("youraddress")

Comment: ok thanks, ill give that a go

Comment: i have some good solutions if you would like to review my posts.